# How to filter matrix with field parameter in rows, based on slicer selection of another value?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to display a matrix with a measure in the values (let's call it "Sales"), with dates in the columns and a category in the rows. Something like this:

| sales | 1/1/2024 | 1/2/2024 | 1/3/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team A | 20 | 41 | 3 |
| team B | 6 | 18 | 7 |
| team C | 88 | 16 | 31 |

But I also have a slicer to filter this matrix, and depending on the selection I want the rows to change.

[**slicer**]

- [category 1]
- [category 2]
- [category 3]
- [category 4]
- [category 5]

| sales | 1/1/2024 | 1/2/2024 | 1/3/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store x | 20 | 41 | 3 |
| store y | 6 | 18 | 7 |
| store z | 88 | 16 | 31 |

so let's say for categories 1, 4 and 5 the matrix should show "team" and 2 and 3 should show "store".

I have a field parameter that includes "team" and "store" but in the matrix it always shows in the rows as a hierarchy.

| sales | 1/1/2024 | 1/2/2024 | 1/3/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store x |  |  |  |
| _______team 1 |  |  |  |
| store z |  |  |  |
| _______team 2 |  |  |  |
| store y |  |  |  |
| _______team 3 |  |  |  |

I can't figure out how to filter the field parameter based on the slicer selection of another value, to one or the other only.

I've tried messing with selection tables, relationships, etc